# Script not accessing GoogleAPI for jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-api

I have this in the head section of all my pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

for whatever reason, it doesn't access Google's API and jQuery doesn't work on my website. However, if I download the code and put it in a .js file, it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="js/jquery-library.js"></script>
```

Any idea why one would work and not the other?

Comment: no reason it shouldn't work. Has nothing to do with your site or server since the browser makes the request directly to the CDN. Perhaps you are using a different version locally and the other one isn't compatible with your code? Check for errors thrown in browser console

Comment: I changed it from "http" to "https" and it works fine now. The website uses an SSL connection so I'm assuming this is why it didn't work with the old link.

Comment: simple way around that is `src="//ajax.googleapis.com/aj...."` will pull from whichever protocol you are on